# how to pass #defined VALUE from QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, defined

taking into account that I have a static `VALUE` which is already defined in a header file (that contains other defined static values) as follow:

```
#defined VALUE  2
```

I would like to update the `VALUE` by passing the text taken from a `QComboBox` to the `#defined` in mainwindow.cpp, so, I am using the following line:

```
#defined VALUE ui->QComboBoc->currentText();
```

but is not working, what exactly I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you learn about the C++ preprocessor, `VALUE` is fixed at compile time.  You will have to replace it with a global static variable, or even better fix your [architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't change the architecture as I am a member of a big team. So, my focus now is on how to update this fixed value to what I might need.

Comment: @user2390046 I don't think you understand the situation, you cannot *update* a *fixed* value - that's an oxymoron.

Comment: Ok, I will try to change my approach to something else .. thanks anyway

Comment: I will try to remove the defined VALUE from the header file and defined it within my code

Comment: @user2390046: I wouldn't focus on the word "architecture". You're tasked with changing `VALUE`. That means it must become a _variable_. Your team will understand this. Also, you should connect the `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` signal to a slot, and from that slot update the `VALUE` variable.